# Constrained optimization with one constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following problem $$\underset{x_s, x_r}{Max} \space x_r(1-q)(m-1)+x_sq(m-1)\\subject 
 \space to:x_r(1-q)+x_sq\leq\alpha$$.

Where $x_s,x_r\in[0,1]$, $q\in(0,1)$ and $m>1. $ I find the following solution: $x_r^*=\frac{\alpha-x_s^*q}{1-q}$ and $x_s^*=\frac{\alpha-x_r^*(1-q)}{q}.$ The constraint, naturally, binds. Is this a correct characterization? Thank you.

Comment: is $m-1$ positive or negative?

Comment: apologies; it is positive.

Comment: I don't understand your solution because you express $x_r^*$ in terms of $x_s^*$

Comment: Substituting out $m-1$ from the objective function, we get: $(m-1)[x_r(1-q)+x_s(q)]$. This is maximised when the second term is equal to $\alpha.$ This implies the optimal values of $x_r$ and $x_s$ I have noted above.

Comment: I would expect an answer in the form of "$x_r^*=(\alpha-x_s^*q) / (1-q)$ for any $x_s^* \in [a,b]$", where $a$ and $b$ are such that $x\in[0,1]$ for any choice of $\alpha$